# Close & re-open putty serial port

Tags: session, serial-port, putty

Can I 'close' the serial port from putty?

I have another C# program that only opens the port when it needs to do its business and promptly closes the port when it's done. I can therefore open up putty, start a session, and interact with the serial line, but I can't seem to figure out how get putty to *close* the port so I can go back to the first program. I could close putty, but then I lose the data in the window and have to re-open putty when I need it again, so that's not a good solution.

I've found that I can force putty into an 'inactive' state by *physically* unplugging the USB-serial adapter I'm using - this causes a '`PuTTY Fatal Error: Error reading from serial device`', which then puts the session into an 'inactive' state (title bar reads '`COM3 - PuTTY (inactive)`') and adds a menu bar command to 'Restart Session'. I can plug the adapter back in and use it with the first program and then restart the putty session (with the aforementioned command) and continue the process. But obviously I'd like to be able to do this without physically unplugging the adapter...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try reconfiguring `putty` to use a different serial port; that should close the current serial port and keep the session active.

Comment: @sawdust, I tried that as well, but putty doesn't let you change the port once it's opened - the option disappears from the settings dialog. I even tried applying settings from another saved session that used a different port, and that didn't change the port either. Good thought, though.

Comment: Consider using a different terminal emulator program that would let you change the serial port connection.  Minicom (for Linux), TeraTerm and even Hyperterminal (although very awkward) can do this on the fly.

Comment: @sawdust, HyperTerminal actually works pretty well. It's not included in Windows since XP, but that's an easy fix, and HT is certainly better than physically unplugging the serial cable...